# Comment on magento contact us form

Tags: php, magento-1.8

I want to make comment as optional part of contact us page. I have removed the class that validates the comment on the contact us form.

```
<li class="wide">
    <label for="comment"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comments or Questions:') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" cols="5" rows="3" ></textarea>
    </div>
</li>
```

it does not show any frontend error but if i don't write any comment i get error message "Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later".

After Help of TBI I found following error -

```
exception 'Exception' in 
/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php:92 Stack trace: #0 
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Contacts_IndexController->postAction() #1 
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post') #2 
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) #3 
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() #4 
/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #5 
/index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store') #6 {main}
```

Comment: Try to print post data in controller if any error occurs there ?

Comment: To solve it we have to change core file comment on bellow line of /app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php
`//if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
//    $error = true;
//}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it we have to change core file.
Just comment bellow line of code on contact module of core the path is 
/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

```
//if(!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) { // $error = true; //}
```

hope this will help others

Answer (score 0):

Better to override the core file.

Copy it to: `app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/` and make your changes to this file. This really helps you know which files you've altered in the course of trying to make Magento work for you.

Comment: Thank you @Chris K for replay. I will keep this in mind for next edit

Comment: Also it is worth setting up a Git repository for version control. Extremely helpful to get a known snapshot in between developments.